# Using #define inside initializer list

Tags: c++

Recently I came across a piece of code similar to this one here

```cpp
std::map<size_t,std::string> map{
#define RT_OK 0
    {RT_OK,"No Error"},
#define RT_SIZE_MISMATCH 1
    {RT_SIZE_MISMATCH,"Size Mismatch"}
};
```

using `#define` just inside the initializer list.

I was actually surprised that it worked with GCC and it seems to work with CLANG too. Anyway is it ok to use `#define` inside an initializer list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "OK"<sup>1</sup> to put macro definitions anywhere<sup>2</sup>.

Pre-processor directives are removed by the pre-processor. The compiler sees something like:

```
std::map<size_t,std::string> map{
// there was a PP directive here
    {0,"No Error"},
// there was a PP directive here
    {1,"Size Mismatch"}
};
```

<sup>1</sup> In the sense that the program is well-formed. It may sometimes be not OK because it may be confusing to other programmers.

<sup>2</sup> Restrictions apply. There must not be any non-whitespace tokens on the same line prior to the directive, and the directive continues until the end of the line.